# My question regarding surya namaskar yoga asanas is marked as duplicate

Tags: support

[My question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28050/5212) regarding Surya namaskar yoga asanas is marked as duplicate. The question which was mentioned is about suryanamaskar mantras and not asanas. My question is about suryanamaskar 12 yoga asanas. This is clear incapacity of the users to understand and comprehend what is duplicate and what is not. So please open my question.

Comment: It's too early to ask on meta. Your question is in review and it currently has 3 votes. What did moderators say about your flag? Wait for some time.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ok. Moderators have not said anything now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is now reopened by users after some modification. I think your flag is also marked helpful. So, relax and wait for someone to answer.